# Python, compact way to yield from a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I have a generator that I'd like to be yielded.

```
def foo():
    a = map(lambda x: x*2, range(5))
    # I want a better way to the next few lines
    # The one that looks more functional
    for i in a:
        yield i
```

I have maps, filters etc. That I'd like to be yielded, is there an alternative way to do it? I looked in `itertools` and `functools`, I couldn't find anything.

Edit:

To be more clearer, I want a way such that it returns one value at each function call.

Comment: Search the docs for `yield from`

Comment: `yield from a` maybe?

Comment: A map object is not a generator (also missing `)`)

Comment: The top scoring answer in the linked question has good info about `yield from` https://stackoverflow.com/a/18620655/4014959

Comment: BTW, I assume it's just a toy example, but using a lambda as the function arg of `map` is a code smell. Write a generatod expression instead. That way you avoid a slow Python function call on each iteration.

Comment: @PM2Ring, @Delegan, `yield from a` returns the entire thing, not like when you use `yield` and can get one value at a time.

Comment: `yield from some_iterable` does the same thing as `for i in some_iterable: yield i`. If you disagree, show us a [mcve] (with output) that demonstrates the difference. FWIW, I've used `yield from` a lot, it's very handy in recursive generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `yield from` (python version has to be >= 3.3);

```
def foo():
    a = map(lambda x: x*2, range(5))
    yield from a
```

Or any version, can use `iter`:

```
def foo():
    a = map(lambda x: x*2, range(5))
    return iter(a)
```

`iter` is equivalent to generator:

```
(i for i in seq)
```

Full example:

```
def foo():
    a = map(lambda x: x*2, range(5))
    return (i for i in a)
```

#### Update:

```
a = iter(map(lambda x: x*2, range(5)))
def foo():
    return next(a)

print(foo())
print(foo())
```

Output:

```
0
2
```

By the way in this case it's a `map`, so no need `iter`:

```
a = map(lambda x: x*2, range(5))
def foo():
    return next(a)

print(foo())
print(foo())
```

Output:

```
0
2
```

Comment: All of these return the entire generator, I'm looking for one that returns one value at a time in each function call.

Comment: @VasanthaGaneshK edited mine

Comment: I understand now that either way is the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @VasanthaGaneshK Please accept if works

Comment: @VasanthaGaneshK Happy that i helped,

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh yeah that's right, because `map`

Comment: @PM2Ring Edited mine